# Calculate the image size in bytes

Tags: java, image, colors, pixel, image-size

I read a article there is how they calculate the image size, but i don't understand how do they get 440kB from 90,000Bytes.

500x300 image (150,000 pixels)

24-bit color:  150,000 pixels x 24 bits/pixel / 8bits/byte =90,000 bytes ~=440kb

Comment: 150000 bytes * 3 (24 bits is 3 bytes) = 450000 bytes = 440Kb

Comment: I have a question is what the unit of pixel?? bit or byte??
150,000 pixels/bit or 150,000 pixels/byte??

Comment: Since you're considering a 24-bit colour palette, a pixel is 3 bytes in size. But with other palettes with less colours (16-bit, 8-bit, etc), pixel size can vary.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the most common image formats (such as JPEG or PNG) compress the data and therefore are smaller in size.